# Arduino error while uploading: Board is not selected

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

My code:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;
const int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalRead(ledPin, buttonPin) ? digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH) : digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException: Board is not selected
    at cc.arduino.Compiler.build(Compiler.java:168)
    at processing.app.SketchController.build(SketchController.java:647)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:672)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2168)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Board is not selected
```

It's saying that the board is not selected, but I selected the board, /dev/ttyUSB0. I tried

```
usermod -a -G uucp sudo0272
usermod -a -G uucp root
```

Because when I was installing the Arduino IDE, it said to do like this. What's the problem and how can I fix this error?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: then, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide your device model since some models have known issues/fixes over others (i.e. UNO vs Nano).

Regardless, this seems to be a setup issue between your device USB driver and the Arduino IDE. It could be as simple as you haven't select the Board and Port in the menu... or could be an issue with the drivers (outdated, corrupt, missing!, etc)

## **First,**

check to make sure you've selected the correct board in the IDE menu:
[image]

## **Then**,

check the right COM Port is selected. This will vary depending on the USB port you're plugged-in to:

[image]

Hopefully this helps! You'll need to provide further info about your situation if still having problems.